# Windows batch For loop not working on one server, working on other

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, for-loop

I've got a Windows 2008 Server (non-R2); I was trying to modify an attribute (/AppPool/maxProcesses) based on a list of application pools.
So I did this:

```
set appcmd=c:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe
for /f %p in (c:\apppools.txt) do @%appcmd% set apppool %p /processmodel.maxProcesses:2
```

No output. Also, this was all interactive, not a batch file.
Usually, it should display the AppPools, and the fact that it's setting the attribute, or an error, in case of typos.

I then went on to verify why wouldn't it output

```
for /f %p in (c:\apppools.txt) do @echo %p
```

Nothing again.
I go to another Windows 2008 (they are actually sysprepped, so considered to be identical. Both commands work!

Has anyone seen anything like this, or at least similar?
I was thinking this server might need its sleep (a reboot) but that might only be possible over the weekend, since it is a server.

Thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Are you sure C:\apppools.txt is not a 0-byte file on the machine where it doesn't work?  Sounds like it's empty.  If not, what are the contents?

Comment: Nope, I'm afraid it's not empty.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know sends a post instead of a newline on mobile.. Nope, I'm afraid it's not empty. I also opened up the file in notepad, copied it, closed notepad, removed the file, and recreated it to make sure it doesn't contain any weird chars. It contains the output of appcmd list apppools on that server. And on another (different server) I've created the same file, same output. Honestly, it's like Windows has gone bananas on that server. Tried a few batch loops in Powershell on the sick server, worked perfectly.

Comment: Try `type c:\apppools.txt` on the bad server and see if the output is what you expect.

Comment: That works, it returns the apppools:
    ASP.NET v4.0
    ASP.NET v4.0 Classic
    Classic .NET AppPool
    DefaultAppPool
    [...]
(I'm guessing that the Comment feature removes formatting.. They are one app pool per line).

Comment: Maybe spaces are an issue?  Try this `for /f "delims=" %p in (c:\apppools.txt) do @echo %p`.  Seems like you probably want that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this from inside a batch file, you will need to escape the % in your for loop variable with another %.

```
for /f %%p in (c:\apppools.txt) do @echo %%p
```

**edit**
Sorry, I just noticed now that you said it was interactive and not batch.

Comment: No problem, and thanks for the reply. Anyway I do believe this is a glitch.... of some kind. Never seen this before on any Windows or other OS for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the file is hidden on one system and not the other, or if it is hidden on both, that hidden files are processed differently on the 2 systems.

Try using a combination of the comments already provided.

```
for /f "delims=" %p in ('type c:\apppools.txt') do @echo %p
```